# Baixar arquivo direto do FTP

Tags: php, ftp

Como faço para baixar um arquivo direto do FTP sem precisar baixar temporariamente no servidor do PHP?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código:

```
<?php
     //....
     $fcon = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
     $conecta = ftp_login($fcon, $ftp_username, $ftp_senha);
     ftp_pasv($fcon, true);
     ftp_chdir($fcon , $ftp_pasta);

     $arquivo = basename($arquivo_ftp);

     $arquivo_temp = "../anexos/" . $arquivo;

     ftp_get($fcon, $arquivo_temp, $arquivo, FTP_BINARY); 


     ftp_close($fcon);

     //Prepara o arquivo para download no navegador
     $file = $arquivo;

     //Vê a extensão do arquivo
     $type = filetype($arquivo_temp);

     //Vê o tamanho do arquivo
     $size = filesize($arquivo_temp);

    //Seta o header da página para forçar o navegador a fazer download
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type:{$type}");
    header("Content-Length:{$size}");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");

    //Faz download
    readfile($arquivo_temp);

    //Apaga o arquivo temporário
    unlink($arquivo_temp);
```

Da forma que está no código acima, o arquivo precisa ser buscado do FTP e baixado temporariamente pra uma pasta do servidor, e depois enviado pro usuário. Com isso arquivos muito grandes e a grande quantidade de usuários está deixando a rede lenta.

Como posso fazer com que autentique no FTP através do PHP e faça um link direto do download entre usuário e FTP?

Comment: Se os ficheiros são parte do processo e precisam estar no mesmo servidor, por quê não utilizar as horas ociosas para transferir o conteúdo do FTP para o servidor e só permitir o download quando o ficheiro estiver disponível no mesmo servidor? Ou por quê não implementar um sistema de downloads (via token, por exemplo) no mesmo servidor em que se encontra os ficheiros e o download ocorrer a partir desse servidor?

Comment: O php sempre vai rodar do lado do servidor, portanto ou você redireciona o utilizador para o arquivo no servidor ftp com um link direto (se não tiver problema de quem tiver o link poder fazer esse download) ou faz como o @FilipeMoraes disse e manter os dados no mesmo servidor para não ser necessária essa cópia ou usar um sistema de downloads por token.

Comment: Uma cópia no servidor é impossível. Esse servidor da aplicação tem N clientes. Cada cliente tem seu FTP próprio. Assim, no mínimo a aplicação possui uns 400 clientes (empresas).

Comment: @FilipeMoraes poderia dar um exemplo de download via token? Como implementar etc...

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo a requisição seria do usuário para o ftp, mas como o ftp é autenticado não sei como fazer. Dai a melhor explicação eu criei essa imagem.

Comment: Os servidores web e ftp estão na mesma secção de rede? Se sim, veja a possibilidade de mapear o diretório FTP no servidor Web, retirando a necessidade de cópia dos dados, mas haveria um mapeamento local. Implementar o download via token não vai resolver a questão do FTP ser autenticado.

Comment: @Fernando cada ftp está em um servidor diferente. Quando o cliente compra licenças do sistema e ele já possui um FTP, apenas configuramos a conexão.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução possível de fazer é utilizando a [Biblioteca Client URL](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php)

Veja como funciona:

```
//Configuração de conexão com o FTP
$ftp_arquivo = "pasta/pasta/meuarquivo.txt";
$ftp_host = "199.99.854.99"; //exemplo
$ftp_port = "21";
$ftp_username = "usuarioAtenticacaoFTP";
$ftp_senha = "MinhaSenhaFTP";


header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($ftp_arquivo) . "\"");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

//Configura a conexão curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,  "ftp://$ftp_host:$ftp_port/$ftp_arquivo"); //Caminho do arquivo
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$ftp_username:$ftp_senha"); //Faz a autenticação
curl_exec ($ch); //Executa

curl_close($ch);
```

Dessa maneira o arquivo não precisa ser baixado temporariamente no servidor do `PHP`.

O `PHP` apenas realiza a **autenticação com o FTP** e o arquivo é baixado diretamente para o browser do usuário.

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Pode usar o "protocolo" `php://` por exemplo o `php://temp`, assim:

```
 <?php
 $fcon = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
 $conecta = ftp_login($fcon, $ftp_username, $ftp_senha);
 ftp_pasv($fcon, true);
 ftp_chdir($fcon , $ftp_pasta);

 $arquivo = basename($arquivo_ftp);

 $arquivo_temp = "php://temp";

 ftp_get($fcon, $arquivo_temp, $arquivo, FTP_BINARY); 


 ftp_close($fcon);

 //Prepara o arquivo para download no navegador
 $file = $arquivo;

 //Vê a extensão do arquivo
 $type = filetype($arquivo_temp);

 //Vê o tamanho do arquivo
 $size = filesize($arquivo_temp);

//Seta o header da página para forçar o navegador a fazer download
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type:{$type}");
header("Content-Length:{$size}");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");

//Faz download
readfile($arquivo_temp);
```

Note que por padrão o limite é de 2MB, então se for maior terá que ajustar nas configurações, ou então pode optar por usar `php://output` combinado com `ob_start`, assim:

```
 <?php
 ob_start();

 $fcon = ftp_connect($ftp_host);
 $conecta = ftp_login($fcon, $ftp_username, $ftp_senha);
 ftp_pasv($fcon, true);
 ftp_chdir($fcon , $ftp_pasta);

 $arquivo = basename($arquivo_ftp);

 $arquivo_temp = "php://output";

 ftp_get($fcon, $arquivo_temp, $arquivo, FTP_BINARY); 

 ftp_close($fcon);

 //Prepara o arquivo para download no navegador
 $file = $arquivo;

 //Vê a extensão do arquivo
 $type = filetype($arquivo_temp);

 //Vê o tamanho do arquivo
 $size = filesize($arquivo_temp);

//Seta o header da página para forçar o navegador a fazer download
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: {$type}");
header("Content-Length: {$size}");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $file . "\"");
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, mas fiquei com uma dúvida. O arquivo ainda vai pro servidor do PHP ou vai direto para o cliente?

Comment: @FlaviaAndrade vai "direto" para o buffer do output que por sua vez é enviado via download, então não é salvo em nenhum arquivo, esse é o proposito do `php://output` ;) - que pro seu caso acho melhor que `php://temp`, pois o temp tem limite de tamanho de 2mb por padrão.